# I need it to return 0 if blank with jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML form which passes the date and time to JavaScript to have some things done to it. The jQuery used to pass the variable to JavaScript is:

```
var pieces;
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#datepicker').datepicker({
          onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            window.pieces = dateText.split('/');
            $('#day').val(pieces[0]);
            $('#month').val(pieces[1]);
            $('#year').val(pieces[2]);  

        }
    })
});
```

The JavaScript used to analyze this uses:

```
var day1 = parseInt(pieces[1],10);
```

How can I parse this so that a blank value for datepicker returns anything but an error telling me it doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably the initial string is something like 15/05/2013.

> The JS used to analyze this uses:
>
> var day1 = parseInt(pieces[1],10);
>
> How can I parse this so that a blank value for datepicker returns anything but an error telling me it doesn't exist?

I'm not sure what you're asking. If you mean "if the original string is blank, I want a value for *day1* of `0`", then you can check for a value and either return the value as a Number or 0 depending on the result of the test:

```
var day1 = typeof pieces[1] == 'undefined' ? +pieces[1] : 0;
```

Incidentally, from your code, *day1* should be *peices[0]*.

Comment: Ah yes basically, if the user doesn't put a value in it must give a value of 0. I will try this out thank you

Comment: thank you ! I have tested it using typeof and it works perfectly~ you're a life saver

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to check the length of the returned array (from `split`):

```
if(window.pieces.length == 3) //an empty string in split does always return 1 element 
{
    alert('date is valid');
}
```

a much better way is to use regular expressions and check the returned value:

```
if(dateText.test(/^(19|20)\d\d[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/))
{
    alert('date is valid');
}
```

the regex is just copied from http://www.regular-expressions.info/dates.html and does not exactly meet your requirements.

The code is not tested...

Comment: `an empty string in split does always return 1 element` is misleading. It will return an empty array (i.e. one with no "elements" or "members"). Also, the regular expression doesn't actually test if it's a valid date, only that the format meets certain criteria.

Comment: Both wrong..., `"".split("/").length` is 1, please tell me the definition of a valid date. There are about 100 definitions of valid dates. And all matches with this regex are valid dates. Despite the fact that I wrote that I do not know his exact requirements regarding the date.

Comment: Philipp — yes, I should have said "may" not "will".

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a test inside of onSelect to handle a blank date.

```
onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
  if(dateText) {  // newline
    window.pieces = dateText.split('/');
    $('#day').val(pieces[0]);
    $('#month').val(pieces[1]);
    $('#year').val(pieces[2]);  
  }
}
```